# How to overload and compile pure functions operating on associations

Tags: compile, functional-style, pure-function

I am writing a small package for myself for operating on zonotopes. 
I am storing the generator matrix and the center of the zonotope in 
an association. I decided to write a small constructor:

```
Zonotope = <| G-> #1, c->#2 |>&;
Z1 = Zonotope[{{1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1}},{0,0}];
```

I can now define a function:

```
AffineTransformZonotope = <|G -> #1.(#2[G]), c -> #1.(#2[c])|>] &;
```

such that calling `AffineTransformZonotope[ A, Z1 ]` (where `A` is a matrix of appropriate dimensions) gives me `Z1` transformed by `A`.

Now, I want to do several overloads on my functions, for example I want a construction that takes an integer `n` and returns a unit n-dimensional cube:

```
Zonotope = <|G->IdentityMatrix[n], c->ConstantArray[0,n]|>&;
```

as well as overloading `AffineTransformZonotope[{A,b},Z1]` to take a matrix `A` and the vector `b` and return the appropriate zonotope. Of course, I want to return an error message whenever there is no appropriate overloaded function.

I know I could to this defining several rules, e.g.

```
Zonotope[n_Integer /; n > 1] := <|G->IdentityMatrix[n],c->ConstantArray[0,n]|>;
Zonotope[Gmat_ /; MatrixQ[Gmat], cvec_ /; VectorQ[cvec]] :=
    If[ Dimensions[Gmat][[1]] == Length[cvec] , 
    <|G -> Gmat, c -> cvec|>,
   (Message[Zonotope::badarg, {Gmat, cvec}]; $Failed)
   ];
```

Similar rules can be defined for the `AffineTransformZonotope` function.

I would like to know if I can avoid rules and work entirely with pure functions: I want to later compile and thread lists of zonotopes and 
affine transformations and then perhaps take the Minkowski sum over the list...

Furthermore, I was wondering if there is any way to compile to C when 
using Associations. I noticed that when I tried it was calling the uncompiled version. If there is no support, is there any better way to emulate such a structure?.

P.S. I wanted to use the tag: function-overloading, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Function overloading is not possible with pure functions. Of couse, you can use pure functions and do the type checking in a humongous `If`/`Which` construction.  I would not advise doing so. Moreover, `Association`s are not compilable.  So you will have to formulate everything in terms of arrays to compile it later.

Comment: Hey @HenrikSchumacher, thanks for the info. I did try the Which/Switch thing but as you correctly point out just gets horrible. So there is no way of emulating structures and compile to C? What do you mean by formulate everything in terms of arrays and compile later?.

Comment: When using `Compile`, you have to restrict to a few classical C trype: Arrays of real and complex numbers (both machine precision), arrays of integers (`long long` IIRC), and `True` and `False` (for booleans). In particular, `Compile` does not like `Association`s. But that is usually not a big restriction as `CompiledFunctions` should only be created for very localized tasks that involve a big deal of number crunching (and only for those taks that cannot be done more efficiently by linear algebra).